# didBeginContact reconize all physicsBody (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a Ball (categoryBitMask = 1, Contact =2), 
walls (categoryBitMask = 2, Contact = 1) 
and a Ground (with PhysicsBody for Ball to drop down)

I set physicsBody for all of it.

But I just want to Ball and Walls contact, not Ball with Ground.

In didBeginContact() when Ball drop to Ground, it's also called.

How can i ?

Comment: Show the exact code you are using (eg. how you set bit masks from Ball and a Ground). In short : `ball.contactTestBitMask = Collider.Wall.rawValue` and `ground.contactTestBitMask = 0` (you don't have to explicitly set this, because it is a default value). See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31111039/3402095

Answer (score 0):

In the category Enum, set 3 categories: (land, walls, Ball).

To set nil Contact for Ball and Land, I just set Contact for walls, not for Ball and Land:

```
wallsNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = categoryType.walls.rawValue
```

To make ball not contact with Land, do this:

```
wallsNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = categoryType.ball.rawValue | categoryType.land.rawValue
```

And this:

```
wallsNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = categoryType.ball.rawValue | categoryType.land.rawValue
```